# Javamail Error-Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jakarta-mail

So i´m trying to send an email to a specific person with javamail.
The sender will have to write the email in a edit text and the receiver is predefined like "example@gmail.com".

## Error

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
    W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    W/System.err:     at com.example.android.elaborasoftware.GMailSender.doInBackground(GMailSender.java:76)
    W/System.err:     at com.example.android.elaborasoftware.GMailSender.doInBackground(GMailSender.java:16)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

## GMailSender.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


class GMailSender extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;
    private String sender;
    private String password;

    //Class Constructor
    GMailSender(String sender,String password, String email, String subject, String message) {
        //Initializing variables
        this.sender = sender;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
        this.password = password;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        //Configuring properties for gmail
        //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        //Creating a new session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(sender, password);
                    }
                });

        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            try {
                mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email));
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Adding receiver
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject(subject);
            //Adding messageZZ
            mm.setText(message);

            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## Registar.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class registar extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registar);
        final EditText etNome = findViewById(R.id.etNome);
        final EditText etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        final EditText etNumero = findViewById(R.id.etNumero);
        final EditText etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final Button btPedido = findViewById(R.id.btPedido);
        final String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        final String Nome = etNome.getText().toString();
        final String Numero = etNumero.getText().toString();
        final String Password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        btPedido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                            Context context = null;
                            String email_message= Nome + " enviou um pedido de registo pela aplicação android 'ElaboraSoftware' com o número de faturação ou série: " + Numero;
                            GMailSender sm = new GMailSender(Email,Password, "comercial@elabora.pt", "Pedido de registo", email_message);
                            sm.execute();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is my code on the tab that has the button that will send the email.
but everytime i click it, it gives me the error message posted at the beggining.

Comment: did you verified your email and password ?

Comment: yes its all in order

Comment: you should further debug and let us know what you got

Comment: it gives me no error oppening the app only gives me the error that i´ve already specified when i click the button

Comment: It doesn't like your password.  You're doing something wrong.  The [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) might provide some clues.  See also all the links in my response to your previous post.